# axhline affecting plot axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm experimenting with `axhline` and I'm finding unpredictable behavior.  When I add an `axhline` sometimes it completely messes up my `x-axis` sometimes it does not.

## Setup

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2016-03-31')
ts = pd.Series([0. for d in idx], index=idx)
t1 = ts['2016-01'] + 1
t2 = ts['2016-02'] + 2
t3 = ts['2016-03'] + 3
```

### First test plot

[image]

Exactly as I wanted it.

## Problem

Now let's add an `axhline`

```
ax = ts.plot()
ax.axhline(y=1.5)
t1.plot(ax=ax)
t2.plot(ax=ax)
t3.plot(ax=ax)
plt.ylim([-1, 4]);
```

[image]

Not at all what I was expecting!

### However

If I add the `axhline` at the end.

```
ax = ts.plot()
t1.plot(ax=ax)
t2.plot(ax=ax)
t3.plot(ax=ax)
ax.axhline(y=1.5)
plt.ylim([-1, 4]);
```

[image]

No problems.

## WHY!?

Why would the order in which I plot dictate the scale of the x-axis?

#### Versions

```
import matplotlib
print pd.__version__
print matplotlib.__version__

0.18.0
1.5.1
```

Comment: What version of pandas/matplotlib are you using?  I am having trouble reproducing this.

Comment: @wflynny added to question

Comment: The issue comes from the interaction between `axhline` and `DateTime` formatter. I dont get it wo work either. Howeever, for me, the left hand limit is ca year 2000 (the J2000 epoch), not year 1970 (the UNIX epoch) so maybe pandas has changed a little...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the "Problem" plot. You just need to rescale x-axis so that the time scale starts in 2016. If you look at the "Problem" plot very closely then you will see there are three dots at the right end of the plot.

A quick way to fix it:

```
ax = ts.plot()
ax.axhline(y=1.5)
t1.plot(ax=ax)
t2.plot(ax=ax)
t3.plot(ax=ax)
plt.autoscale()
plt.ylim([-1, 4])
plt.show()
```

Seems like in pyplot if you create `axhline` first, you have to rescale before you do `plt.show()`.

Comment: This is exactly why I say it's a problem.  Why would the order in which I plot dictate the scale of the x-axis?

Comment: I see, it's my bad. You can add `plt.autoscale()` before you do `plt.show()`. Looks like pyplot doesn't rescale automatically.

Comment: Please put that in your answer.

Comment: `plt.autoscale()` wont do it for me... :(